# Having 4 columns in a row with Boostrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4.5.1 to display 4 columns, looking like this.

Actual display of my 4 columns.

[image: 1]

I want those 4 columns to be aligned in a single row (they shouldn't wrap).

Here's the code:

**html**

```html
<div class="container flex-nowrap">
            <div class="featured-boxes">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="<?= $this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Academy' , 'action' => 'index', 'language' => $this->request->getSession()->read('Config.language')]); ?>">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="featured-box featured-box-primary featured-box-effect-1 mt-xlg" style="height: 358px;">
                                <div class="box-content">
                                    <i class="icon-featured fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
                                    <h4 class="text-uppercase"><?= __('Academy'); ?></h4>
                                    <p><?= __(''); ?></p>
                                    <?= $this->Html->image('academy.png', ['alt' =>  __('Academy'), 'class' => 'img-responsive img-rounded']); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="<?= $this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Esports' , 'action' => 'index', 'language' => $this->request->getSession()->read('Config.language')]); ?>">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="featured-box featured-box-primary featured-box-effect-1 mt-xlg" style="height: 358px;">
                                <div class="box-content">
                                    <i class="icon-featured fa fa-gamepad"></i>
                                    <h4 class="text-uppercase"><?= __('Esports'); ?></h4>
                                    <p><?= __(''); ?></p>
                                    <?= $this->Html->image('esports.png', ['alt' => __('Esports')]); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="<?= $this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Posts','action' => 'view','bar']); ?>">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="featured-box featured-box-primary featured-box-effect-1 mt-xlg" style="height: 358px;">
                                <div class="box-content">
                                    <i class="icon-featured fa fa-trophy"></i>
                                    <h4 class="text-uppercase"><?= __('Events'); ?></h4>
                                    <p><?= __(''); ?></p>
                                    <?= $this->Html->image('events.png', ['alt' => __('Events')]); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="<?= $this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Posts','action' => 'view','bar']); ?>">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="featured-box featured-box-primary featured-box-effect-1 mt-xlg" style="height: 358px;">
                                <div class="box-content">
                                    <i class="icon-featured fa fa-group"></i>
                                    <h4 class="text-uppercase"><?= __('Gaming'); ?></h4>
                                    <p><?= __(''); ?></p>
                                    <?= $this->Html->image('gaming.png', ['alt' => __('Gaming')]); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**EDIT:**

I modified my code to use *col-sm-3* instead of *col-sm* for every column in the row. But now, the boxes are no more responsive. Why?

Here's the result I'm getting when shrinking the window by setting *col-sm col-md-3* for every column:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A79U0.png)

*EDIT 2:**

I resolved my issue by using Boostrap *img-fluid* class for my images.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Beautify of row column layout whenever width of resolution get reduce it will adjust to it. Just check what resolution your are checking. Ideally 12 divided by 4 column fit in single row.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm really new to Boostrap, I don't really understand what should I change. Speaking about the resolution, I want the columns to be wrapped at the Grid breakpoints, but on a computer (higher than 992px), I want the 4 fours columns to be displayed on a single row.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/ explained here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing each "col-sm" to "col-sm-3" - then you are setting the width instead of letting Bootstrap choose its own?

Comment: That was it, thank you! But can you please tell me where I'm defining the width as a static one? I don't see it...

Comment: Using what you said doesn't make the columns responsive btw

Comment: You have to imagine your page is split into 12 columns. What you are actually saying by defining the 3 on the end is that the on a small display upwards each column covers 3 of those 12 columns so 4 on a row.

You could leave the code as you had it and just add "col-md-3" to the class so it says "col-sm col-md-3" and then only on devices bigger than the small resolution does it show 4 columns below that it would wrap them automatically.

Comment: Can you please check the image I added during the edit please? I tried what you said, but it's not rendering as expected (did I do it wrong?)

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap guidelines dictates that if you want to have a `row` that contains `columns`. A row consists of 12 columns, so you if you want to have 4 columns, each column should have a space of 3. The class to use in this case should be `col-sm-3` not just `col-sm`.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>  <!-- end of row -->
```

However, your code is not following this standard. You have a `<a></a>` that is a sibling of these columns:

```
<div class="row">
   <a href="#">...</a>
   <div class="col-sm-3">...</div>
   <a href="#">...</a>
   <div class="col-sm-3">...</div>
   <a href="#">...</a>
   <div class="col-sm-3">...</div>
   <a href="#">...</a>
   <div class="col-sm-3">...</div>
</div>
```

You need to move the `<a></a>` link somewhere inside the columns.
Otherwise, make the links themselves columns with proper size:

```
<div class="row">
   <a class="col-sm-3" href="#"> <div></div> </a>
   <a class="col-sm-3" href="#"> <div></div> </a>
   <a class="col-sm-3" href="#"> <div></div> </a>
   <a class="col-sm-3" href="#"> <div></div> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try to, thank you very much! It helped a lot to understand. **Edit:** thx for explaining the row, I didn't understand that a row was containing 12 columns.

Answer (score 2):

A row consists of 12 columns that covers the whole screen. If you want to have 4 columns, each column should have a space of 3. The class to use should be col-sm-3

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are using divs you are using them as containers for the content that you want to show for the page.

You start making a grid (table layout) for your page with the main

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

This div can have two types of main class: "container" - does not take the whole screen (usually 1100 px width) or "container-fluid" takes whole screen, no matter how wide it is.

Then you start each line of your divs (row) inside container with:

```
<div class="row"></div>
```

Row means that you are virtually drawing a row that has 12 cells in it.

[image: Bootstrap Grid System]

As you probably know different devices have different screen resolutions. So on some devices each of 12 cells will be larger, on some smaller. That is when you start using

```
<576px  Extra small .col-
≥576px  Small   .col-sm-    
≥768px Medium   .col-md- 
≥992px  Large   .col-lg-
≥1200px Extra large .col-xl-
```

What this table means that the bootstrap will try to keep divs together on the given size of the screen, based on total 12 available cells. For example if you want you cells to be together on the screen larger that 768, and become responsive on screens with lesser resolution use .col.md

```
<div class="col.md-6"></div>
<div class="col.md-6"></div>
```

Just remember that in any given row the sum of col-smth classes should always add to 12 and not more, you can 3+9, 2+2+2+2+2+2 etc.

When you want to start new row just use new row divs.

So the correct code for a grid of several divs would be smth like

```
<div class="container>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sd-4">Something here</div>
    <div class="col-sd-8"><a></a></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sd-3">Something here</div>
    <div class="col-sd-3">Something here</div>
    <div class="col-sd-3">Something here</div>
    <div class="col-sd-3">Something here</div>
</div>

</div>
```